# unable to resolve grpc-core while building jetcd with maven-bundle-plugin:2.4.0

Tags: maven, osgi, osgi-bundle

I am converting the jetcd library to OSGi bundle using maven-bundle-plugin:2.4.0. I get the below warning for grpc-core. Could you please help me as I am not familiar with the Maven Build intricacies.

```
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:2.4.0:install (default-install)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <attachedArtifacts>${project.attachedArtifacts}</attachedArtifacts>
  <localRepository>${localRepository}</localRepository>
  <obrRepository>${obrRepository}</obrRepository>
  <project>${project}</project>
</configuration>
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for http://15.250.145.102/artifactory/maven_virtual_1 as null
Downloading: http://15.250.145.102/artifactory/maven_virtual_1/io/grpc/grpc-core/1.5.0/grpc-core-1.5.0.pom
Downloaded: http://15.250.145.102/artifactory/maven_virtual_1/io/grpc/grpc-core/1.5.0/grpc-core-1.5.0.pom (3 KB at 2.9 KB/sec)
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file /share/raw/home/staff1/mukundac/.m2/repository/io/grpc/grpc-core/1.5.0/grpc-core-1.5.0.pom.lastUpdated
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file /share/raw/home/staff1/mukundac/.m2/repository/io/grpc/grpc-core/1.5.0/_maven.repositories
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for http://15.250.145.102/artifactory/maven_virtual_1 as null
Downloading: http://15.250.145.102/artifactory/maven_virtual_1/io/grpc/grpc-context/1.5.0/grpc-context-1.5.0.pom
Downloaded: http://15.250.145.102/artifactory/maven_virtual_1/io/grpc/grpc-context/1.5.0/grpc-context-1.5.0.pom (2 KB at 3.2 KB/sec)
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file /share/raw/home/staff1/mukundac/.m2/repository/io/grpc/grpc-context/1.5.0/grpc-context-1.5.0.pom.lastUpdated
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file /share/raw/home/staff1/mukundac/.m2/repository/io/grpc/grpc-context/1.5.0/_maven.repositories
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for http://15.250.145.102/artifactory/maven_virtual_1 as null
Downloading: http://15.250.145.102/artifactory/maven_virtual_1/io/grpc/grpc-context/1.2.0/grpc-context-1.2.0.pom
Downloaded: http://15.250.145.102/artifactory/maven_virtual_1/io/grpc/grpc-context/1.2.0/grpc-context-1.2.0.pom (2 KB at 3.2 KB/sec)
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file /share/raw/home/staff1/mukundac/.m2/repository/io/grpc/grpc-context/1.2.0/grpc-context-1.2.0.pom.lastUpdated
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file /share/raw/home/staff1/mukundac/.m2/repository/io/grpc/grpc-context/1.2.0/_maven.repositories
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for http://15.250.145.102/artifactory/maven_virtual_1 as null
Downloading: http://15.250.145.102/artifactory/maven_virtual_1/io/grpc/grpc-netty/1.5.0/grpc-netty-1.5.0.pom
Downloaded: http://15.250.145.102/artifactory/maven_virtual_1/io/grpc/grpc-netty/1.5.0/grpc-netty-1.5.0.pom (3 KB at 4.6 KB/sec)
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file /share/raw/home/staff1/mukundac/.m2/repository/io/grpc/grpc-netty/1.5.0/grpc-netty-1.5.0.pom.lastUpdated
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file /share/raw/home/staff1/mukundac/.m2/repository/io/grpc/grpc-netty/1.5.0/_maven.repositories
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata io.grpc:grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml in local (/share/raw/home/staff1/mukundac/.m2/repository)
[DEBUG] [DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for http://15.250.145.102/artifactory/maven_virtual_1 as null
Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for http://15.250.145.102/artifactory/maven_virtual_1 as null
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/
Downloading: http://15.250.145.102/artifactory/maven_virtual_1/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external
Downloading: http://15.250.145.102/artifactory/maven_virtual_1/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://15.250.145.102/artifactory/maven_virtual_1/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 0.9 KB/sec)
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file /share/raw/home/staff1/mukundac/.m2/repository/io/grpc/grpc-core/resolver-status.properties
Downloaded: http://15.250.145.102/artifactory/maven_virtual_1/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 0.9 KB/sec)
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file /share/raw/home/staff1/mukundac/.m2/repository/io/grpc/grpc-core/resolver-status.properties
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file /share/raw/home/staff1/mukundac/.m2/repository/io/grpc/grpc-core/resolver-status.properties
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file /share/raw/home/staff1/mukundac/.m2/repository/io/grpc/grpc-core/resolver-status.properties
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata io.grpc:grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml from/to typesafe (http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/): Connection to http://repo.typesafe.com refused
org.sonatype.aether.transfer.MetadataTransferException: Could not transfer metadata io.grpc:grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml from/to typesafe (http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/): Connection to http://repo.typesafe.com refused
```

Comment: First problem, why do you want to use a version of the maven-bundle-plugin that is over 4 years old??

Comment: Your build is trying to download artifacts from a repository: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/. For some reason this failed when you tried. I have just checked that repository URL and it works for me, so either it was temporarily offline when you tried to build, or you have a problem with your local network. So first thing to do is just try again. If it doesn't work then try that URL in your browser.